# Is it possible to compare Guid values using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

I would like to implement cursor based pagination using `uniqueidentifier` column in SQL Server. Is there any way to make this query to run server-side with Entity Framework Core?

```cs
var cursor = Guid.NewGuid();
// This query will not delegate filtering to database
var items = await dbContext.Items.Where(x => x.Id.CompareTo(cursor) > 0).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What happens?

Comment: @DavidG, the warning like "the LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally" is printed out in the debug console.